# Returns a none value always

Tags: python-2.7, return

I was trying to make this binary search tree and was defining its recursive get function. But no matter what i do it always returns None. I m just a newbie...
So sry if the solution is obious or something... But please can anyone tell me why is it returning none value...???

```
def get(self,key):
    if self.root:
        res = self._get(key,self.root)
        if res:
            return res.payload
        else:
            return None
    else:
        return None

def _get(self,key,currentnode):
    if not currentnode:
        return None
    elif currentnode.key==key:
        return currentnode
    elif key<currentnode.key:
        self._get(key,currentnode.leftchild)
    else:
        self._get(key,currentnode.rightchild)
```

I am using a dict at each node with the key being the comparison parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following lines:

```
elif key<currentnode.key:
    self._get(key,currentnode.leftchild)
else:
    self._get(key,currentnode.rightchild)
```

with:

```
elif key<currentnode.key:
    return self._get(key,currentnode.leftchild)
else:
    return self._get(key,currentnode.rightchild)
```

Comment: So answer was a bit too obvious worked like a charm... thnku.. :)